# Memory leak when using OpenMP

Tags: multithreading, gcc, memory-leaks, openmp, allocator

The below test case runs out of memory on 32 bit machines (throwing std::bad_alloc) in the loop following the "post MT section" message when OpenMP is used, however, if the #pragmas for OpenMP are commented out, the code runs through to completion fine, so it appears that when the memory is allocated in parallel threads, it does not free correctly and thus we run out of memory.

Question is whether there is something wrong with the memory allocation and deletion code below or is this a bug in gcc v4.2.2 or OpenMP? I also tried gcc v4.3 and got same failure.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "start " << std::endl;

    {
            std::vector<std::vector<int*> > nts(100);
            #pragma omp parallel
            {
                    #pragma omp for
                    for(int begin = 0; begin < int(nts.size()); ++begin) {
                            for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
                                    nts[begin].push_back(new int(5));
                            }
                    }
            }

    std::cout << "  pre delete " << std::endl;
            for(int begin = 0; begin < int(nts.size()); ++begin) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < nts[begin].size(); ++j) {
                            delete nts[begin][j];
                    }
            }
    }
    std::cout << "post MT section" << std::endl;
    {
            std::vector<std::vector<int*> > nts(100);
            int begin, i;
            try {
              for(begin = 0; begin < int(nts.size()); ++begin) {
                    for(i = 0; i < 2000000; ++i) {
                            nts[begin].push_back(new int(5));
                    }
              }
            } catch (std::bad_alloc &e) {
                    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "begin: " << begin << " i: " << i << std::endl;
                    throw;
            }
            std::cout << "pre delete 1" << std::endl;

            for(int begin = 0; begin < int(nts.size()); ++begin) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < nts[begin].size(); ++j) {
                            delete nts[begin][j];
                    }
            }
    }

    std::cout << "end of prog" << std::endl;

    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I run this under Windows built with the Intel compiler my allocations start failing in the first loop due to hitting the 2gb limit for a 32 bit process. Is it possible that the overhead of OpenMP is just pushing your process over whatever the limit is on your platform?

Comment: @Scott Danahy Try changing the test case to cut all allocations in half, this test worked with a 4 GB limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this issue elsewhere seen without OpenMP but just using pthreads. The extra memory consumption when multi-threaded appears to be typical behavior for the standard memory allocator. By switching to the [Hoard](http://www.hoard.org/) allocator the extra memory consumption goes away.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the first OpenMP loop from 1000000 to 2000000 will cause the same error. This indicates that the out of memory problem is with OpenMP stack limit.

Try setting the OpenMP stack limit to unlimit in bash with

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

You can also change the OpenMP environment variable OMP_STACKSIZE and setting it to 100MB or more.

UPDATE 1: I change the first loop to

```
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int*> > nts(100);
    #pragma omp for schedule(static) ordered
    for(int begin = 0; begin < int(nts.size()); ++begin) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2000000; ++i) {
            nts[begin].push_back(new int(5));
        }
    }

    std::cout << "  pre delete " << std::endl;
    for(int begin = 0; begin < int(nts.size()); ++begin) {
        for(int j = 0; j < nts[begin].size(); ++j) {
            delete nts[begin][j]
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I get a memory error at i=1574803 on the Main thread.

UPDATE 2: If you are using the Intel compiler, you can add the following to the top of your code and it will solve the problem (providing you have enough memory for the extra overhead).

```
std::cout << "Previous stack size " << kmp_get_stacksize_s() << std::endl;
kmp_set_stacksize_s(1000000000);
std::cout << "Now stack size " << kmp_get_stacksize_s() << std::endl;
```

UPDATE 3: For completeness, like mentioned by another member, if you are performing some numerical computation, it is best to preallocate everything in a single **new float[1000000]** instead of using OpenMP to do 1000000 allocations. This applies to allocating objects as well.

Comment: When you change the first loop to 2000000, what's the total allocated size for the process when it fails to allocate new memory?

Comment: i=1574803 when it crashes. See my UPDATE 1.

Comment: @Dat Chu So without using Intel compiler (i.e. using gcc) the OMP_STACKSIZE env var setting is the way to go because the kmp_set_stacksize_s() is not available in gcc?

Comment: Yes. Make sure that you either specify the values in KB or give the correct suffix http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/OMP_005fSTACKSIZE.html

Comment: @DatChu I tried running with OMP_STACKSIZE=100M and also tried ulimit but it still fails for me with begin=76 and i=1048576 in the updated example code in the question yet if OpenMP is not used, the code completes without running out of memory.

Comment: @DatChu Why the pragma change from my example to instead be '#pragma omp for schedule(static) ordered'?

Comment: @WilliamKF: I don't have access to a Linux machine with anything less than 8GB of RAM but I will try to find one so I can test it under Linux. Re:pragma change, it is easier for me to debug if it is a ordered static scheduling. You can simply use #pragma omp parallel for

Comment: @DatChu Just build -m32 for a 32 bit executable and you will run out of memory on machine with 8GB.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `int*` as the inner vector member?  That's very wasteful - you have 4 bytes (`sizeof(int)`, strictly) of data and 2-3 times more again of heap control structure for every `vector` entry.  Try this just using `vector<int>` and see if it runs better.

I'm not an OpenMP expert but this usage seems weird in its asymmetry - you fill the vectors in parallel section and clear them in non-parallel code. Cannot tell you whether that's wrong, but it 'feels' wrong.

Comment: @Steve Townsend This test case is meant to show the issue, not to be actual used code.  An array of five ints in each entry helps to consume the memory to demonstrate the leak. Making the code more memory efficient would just cause the failure to be delayed until even more memory was consumed.

Comment: @WilliamKF - I see.  I think you need an OpenMP guru to comment then.  The question asks about *any* problems with memory allocation and deletion, and to me it seemed RAII would be preferable.  I'm adding +1 to your q, as I'm interested in the answer myself.

Comment: Since the code is for demonstration of the problem, it feels a bit awkward but it is not uncommon to have clean-up and post-processing done outside of the OpenMP constructs.

Comment: @Steve Townsend I think the key point here is that turning off OpenMP causes the test case to not run out of memory.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wondered if cleaning up in non-parallel code was problematic.  Another problem could be loop nesting without any thread-private variables.

Comment: @Steve: OpenMP will automatically make the variables in the inner scope thread-private. The problem identified in Dan’s answer is probably the real reason here.

Comment: @Konrad - thanks, I am sure that's it.  Shame, I was hoping to learn some OpenMP magic here.

Comment: @Steve: the good thing about OpenMP is that there’s very little magic. The bad thing is … that there’s very little magic. OpenMP is very rudimentary in many regards. It behaves very much grafted on.

Comment: @SteveTownsend Apparently it is a bug in gcc's malloc()/free() since I see the problem without OpenMP but just posix pthreads and switching out malloc for an alternative such a hoard fixes the problem as I wrote in other answer.